# System crash - owner automatically changed for OSX drive and the external one

Tags: permissions, osx-mavericks

Last night my MBP with Mavericks installed, froze up. When I woke up and noticed, there was an internal system loading wheel.

I shut down my Mac and had waited for the system to load but it crashed and rebooted itself. I got into OSX on reboot, checked the disks with Disk Utility, and they are fine. I have also noticed that OSX had to rebuild the index of all my files.

Lately, I've been working with some files and had to move them on my external drive but have been prompted for administrator password because I had no permission. I've opened the Disk Info dialog and noticed that my username wasn't present in the owner's list, only system, wheel, and everyone.

I added my username and switched the disk owner from system to my username.

After realizing that my system disk has also changed its owner to system, may I switch the owner to myself? Actually, I don't even know if it was a **System** user before the crash. 
Just don't want to break the permissions or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

On my MBP, the Disk Info panel for my internal drive shows:

```
system : read and write
wheel : read only
everyone : read only
```

I'm thinking you weren't supposed to change it from system to your user account, but it also probably doesn't matter (much) since anytime an action is taken that requires system level access it ordinarily would ask you for your administrator password.

But probably best not to mess with it.

Hope you are making TimeMachine (or otherwise) backups of your data.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't changed to my account yet for the main disk, but for the external one, because I've checked other external drives I have and they all have My Username, Staff and Everyone in the ownership pannel. That's why I thought it was the same for the main disk, but since you have it as mine, I'll better leave it as it is.